# Combine function that populates `select` elements with function that pre-selects options matching db values

Tags: php, arrays

I want to modify function *checkSelectedOption* so that I don't have to hardcode the array every time it's called.

The 1rst function pre-selects the option matching the information in the db, but it uses hardcoded arrays to populate `select` elements. The 2nd function creates arrays from db values and dynamically populates `select` elements. How can I combine these two functions so that I can populate `select` elements dynamically, and then pre-select the option matching the information in the db?

*Function checkSelectedOption* populates the element with the values specified in array "$options", and then pre-selects the option matching the information in the "customer_info" table of the db.  This function currently requires that the arrays be hardcoded, and I want to replace this part of the function with the method from *function printSelectOptions* which uses arrays created from db values.

*Function printSelectOptions* populates `select` elements from values fetched from the db. It does this by creating an array with the values in the column fetched from the "form_fields" table.

*Function checkSelectedOption*

```
function checkSelectedOption($dataArray, $currentSelection) {
    foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value) {
        echo '<option ' . (($key == $currentSelection) ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . ' value="' . $key . '">' . $value . '</option>';
    }
}
try {  
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer_info WHERE user_id = :user_id");  
$stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id); 
$stmt->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} 
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

*To call function*

```
<select name="first_name">
    <?php
    // Populates the element with values from array $options         
    $options = array("John"=>"John", "Robert"=>"Robert");
    $selected = $row['first_name'];
    echo checkSelectedOption($options, $selected);
    ?>
</select>
```

*Function printSelectOptions*

```
function printSelectOptions($dataArray, $currentSelection, $fieldname) {
    $output = '';
    foreach ($dataArray as $key => $value) {
    // Only add to array if row has value
    if ($value[$fieldname] !="" && $value[$fieldname] !="Null") {
            $output .= '<option ' . (($key == $currentSelection)) . ' value="' . $key . '">' . str_replace('_', ' ', $value[$fieldname]) . '</option>';
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
try {  
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM form_fields");  
    $stmt->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} 
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

*To call function*

```
<select name="first_name">
    <?php 
    // Dynamically populates element with array created from column first_name
    echo printSelectOptions($rows, $currentSelection, 'first_name');
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand, are you trying to do a multi-select for the first one built from table1? - and you want to select the items based on values from table2?

Comment: @Revent - Yes :-D I'm trying to use the function which preselects the options without having to hardcode each array. I just rewrote the question, so hopefully it's a bit clearer now

Comment: @imsiso Thanks :-) I'm trying to change function 'checkSelectedOption' so that instead of using a hardcoded array it can use an array created from values in the db (like in function 'printSelectOptions')

Comment: Mixing HTML and PHP logic is always a bad idea. You should import functions from somewhere else, not to define them in markups. This would only make your code hard to test and maintain in future.

Comment: @metal_fan - I'm not sure what you're referring to :-( Are you referring to where I define function checkSelectedOption and printSelectOptions? If so, those aren't in the html, they're in the php (at the top of the page). If that's not what you were referring to, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @imsiso lol wut? I'm not talking about neither MVC and MVP, but Separation of Concerns (SoC). Nothing more.

Comment: I failed to see what your actual question is. Couldn't you edit it?

Comment: @imsiso - Yes :-D Which is how I do it in the 2nd function :-)

Comment: @metal_fan - I think that imsiso put it in more technical terms, which might help, and I'm also rephrasing the question a bit now

Comment: @imsiso - I want to be able to do that in the 1rst function

Comment: @metal_fan - I just rephrased the question :-) Is it clearer now?

Comment: @imsiso - Is there something that I can clarify?

Comment: @imsiso - $options is being defined each time I call the function (i.e. $options = array("John"=>"John", "Robert"=>"Robert"); )

Comment: @imsiso I want it to come from the db

Comment: @imsiso - no the query is fine, and I just posted the code for that. I'm just trying to figure out how to modify the function so that I don't have to hardcode the array every time it's called

Comment: @imsiso - I included the example :-) I believe $currentSelection is the array key

Comment: $options is being defined each time I call the function (i.e. $options = array("John"=>"John", "Robert"=>"Robert"); ). The query is too long to post in a comment, but I included it in the question

Comment: @imsiso I don't understand what you're saying :-(

Comment: @imsiso What bad response are you referring to? I actually haven't been on this post in the past 45 min.

Comment: I don't think that $options needs to be queried because it's hardcoded :-(

Comment: That was referring to a <select> element's options (as opposed to $options, which is the hardcoded array)

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, and yes I want to use a query instead. I want to use the query that's in 'printSelectOptions'

Comment: @imsiso It doesn't feel like we're any closer ;-) I don't know how to replace $options with the script from the 2nd function - echo printSelectOptions($rows, $currentSelection, 'first_name');

Comment: @imsiso - what wasn't correct about it?

Comment: Is that just the more correct way to do it, because it was working the way it was?

Comment: I don't understand :-( I've used it on a few hundred elements and they are all working properly :-( What am I missing?

Comment: I don't really understand, but I'll try it in the morning. Also I know you had another question, but I couldn't understand it at all :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @metal_fan, I'm not sure what you're referring to, can you elaborate a
>   bit?

600 chars won't be enough, I guess.

> How can I combine these two functions so that I can populate select
>   elements dynamically and then pre-select the option matching the
>   information in the db?

You have to fetch the data you need then compare it against a value "inside" selectbox inside a loop (or it would be a hell).

PHP itself is meant to be used as a template engine. That means, people should use it as a template engine - Don't `print/echo` html tags, inject php "things" instead.

All what you're doing now doesn't make sense at all. 
The common solution is to create a helper function that does calculation.

Remember, one function should only do single task. If you have several ones, create a function for each one.

**UPDATE**
Well, I'm kinda confused even more now, after your edit.

```
// Assume that array we got from the table looks like:
$array = array('John' => 'John', 'Dave' => 'Dave', 'Jason' => 'Jason');

$__AGAINST__ = 'Jason'; // <-- VERY IMPORTANT

function is_selected($expected, $actual){

    if ( $expected === $actual ){

        print 'selected="selected"';
    }
}

?>

<select>

    <?php foreach($array as $key => $val):?>

    <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>" <?php is_selected($key, $__AGAINST__); ?>><?php echo $val; ?></option>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

</select>
```

`$__AGAINST__` you would take from configuration or something like that. This is what you're comparing against.

Now replace `$__AGAINST__ = 'Jason';` with `$__AGAINST__ = 'Dave';` You see how it works? The core idea is to iterate over `$array` and compare `$key` against something. Nothing more.

**UPDATE 2**

I guess you got an idea how "select against" works. But you didn't understand what I've told you at all :( Look at this:

```
$output .= '<option ' . is_selected($key, $__AGAINST__) . ' value="' . $key . '">' . str_replace('_', ' ', $value[$fieldname]) . '</option>';
```

You're keep making the same mistake again and again. **PHP itself is meant to be used as a template engine**. You should avoid `printing/echoing` *HTML tags*. Why? What if you decide to replace that `select` with another element (say Jquery ComboBox plugin). What happens then? You would have to re-factor the "generation" logic itself as well as a presentation. Sounds so bad. Why sounds bad? This is because presentation should be totally decoupled from application/generation logic. Why should be decoupled? Flexibility, Maintainability would answer this question, I guess.

**Keep your templates as dumb as possible** They should **NEVER** do any calculations directly. If you want to calculate something within a HTML template, then define a function somewhere in *bootstrap.php* (or the like), but not inside a markup itself.

*PHP is meant to be used as a template engine*. **But what does it really mean?**

This means (we are not in Perl/Python), you should ALWAYS avoid code like this one:

```
$ouptut = '<option>' . $foo . '</option>';
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $bad . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

But write something like this instead:

```
<select>
  <option><?php echo $foo; ?></option>
</select>
```

Keeping this thing in mind, you would keep your HTML things totally decouple from PHP parser. Which is great for future maintains.

Comment: That means, instead of doing crazy things like `checkSelectedOption($dataArray, $currentSelection,$fieldName)`, you should iterate over (via `foreach`) inside a markup. The point here : You should "prepare" everything before outputting. By "prepare" I mean, that you'd define functions that do calculation.

Comment: I understood most of what you said, but I'd like to clarify a few things. I'm currently using both of these functions independently, and a lot of my PHP (including several functions) echos html tags, etc. Do I need to change all of that? Or is it specific to functions or this specific scenario?

Comment: If you can, post your table structure and the way you fetch data from a table (via PDO, or whatever)

Comment: @imsiso yeah exactly what I mean.

Comment: Just added the code I use to fetch the data :-) How would you like me to post the table structure?

Comment: Also, I'm having a bit of trouble following the code and applying it  :-( Would you mind using my field names (hopefully that'll help ;-))

Comment: I needed to look at it with fresh eyes, but now I finally understand the idea and got it working :-D I'm just having a bit of trouble integrating it into the printSelectOptions function. Would you mind helping me with that last bit? I tried calling it like this, but it doesn't seem to be working quite right $output .= '<option ' . is_selected($key, $__AGAINST__) . ' value="' . $key . '">' . str_replace('_', ' ', $value[$fieldname]) . '</option>';

Comment: @ChayaCooper updated. And what exactly do you mean by "not quiteright " ? Do you expect a cat, but get a dog instead, or what? :)

Comment: LOL by not quite right, I mean that when I combined it like that it wasn't showing the value as selected so I'm assuming that I'm not calling the function properly

Comment: Do you want an item to be selected, according to what? In the example above, I had a variable `$__AGAINST__`. Yours?   is `$options = array("John"=>"John", "Robert"=>"Robert");` exactly what you want to compare against? If so, I probably did show how it works... If not, post an array and the value you wanna compare against, again, please.

Comment: I was trying it with the hardcoded variable the way you had it - "$__AGAINST__ = 'Jason';"

Comment: On a separate note, I read your update and I think I finally understand what you're saying about decoupling the html and php :-D And it would definitely make things much easier to do it that way :-) Would you be mind showing me how I should change the function/s so that I can do that? I'd be happy to post that as a separate question so that I can accept both answers and to make it easier for other people to find ;-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28535/discussion-between-metal-fan-and-chaya-cooper)